# Parsing error: The keyword 'export' is reserved with @typescript-eslint/parser

Tags: typescript, eslint, typescript-eslint, turborepo

In a turborepo monorepo, I try to load the following ESlint config file, by extending from the package folder

```js
module.exports = {
    extends: ["eslint:recommended", "plugin:import/recommended", "prettier"],
    rules: {
        "prefer-const": "warn",
        "no-console": "warn",
        "no-duplicate-imports": "error",
        "spaced-comment": ["error", "always", { markers: ["/", "!", "?"] }],
        "arrow-body-style": ["warn", "as-needed"],
        "import/no-cycle": "error",
        "import/prefer-default-export": "off",
        "import/extensions": [
            "error",
            "ignorePackages",
            { js: "never", jsx: "never", ts: "never", tsx: "never" },
        ],
    },
    settings: {
        "import/resolver": {
            node: true,
        },
    },
    env: {
        node: true,
        es6: true,
    },
    ignorePatterns: ["node_modules"],
};
```

```js
const { resolve } = require("node:path");

const project = resolve(process.cwd(), "tsconfig.json");

module.exports = {
    parser: "@typescript-eslint/parser",
    parserOptions: {
        project,
    },
    extends: [
        "plugin:@typescript-eslint/recommended",
        "plugin:@typescript-eslint/recommended-requiring-type-checking",
        "plugin:import/typescript",
    ],
    rules: {
        "@typescript-eslint/no-empty-function": "off",
        "@typescript-eslint/no-namespace": "off",
        "@typescript-eslint/no-misused-promises": [
            "error",
            {
                checksVoidReturn: {
                    attributes: false,
                },
            },
        ],
    },
    settings: {
        "import/resolver": {
            typescript: {
                project,
            },
        },
    },
};
```

In the database package I extend those two config files.
I am using typescript with the ESM syntax imports and I get this error `Parsing error: The keyword 'export' is reserved` when linting

When i run

```bash
eslint --print-config index.ts
```

I get

```json
{
  "env": {},
  "globals": {},
  "parser": null,
  "parserOptions": {},
  "plugins": [],
  "rules": {},
  "settings": {},
  "ignorePatterns": []
}
```

which leads me to believe that my config is not loaded properly

Here are some more files

database/package.json

```json
{
    "name": "database",
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "exports": "./index.ts",
    "types": "./index.ts",
    "scripts": {
        "db:generate": "prisma generate",
        "db:push": "prisma db push --skip-generate",
        "format": "prisma format",
        "lint": "eslint . --ext .ts",
        "lint:ts": "tsc --noEmit",
        "studio": "prisma studio"
    },
    "dependencies": {
        "@prisma/client": "^5.3.1"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "@types/node": "^20.6.3",
        "eslint-config-custom": "workspace:*",
        "prisma": "^5.3.1",
        "tsconfig": "workspace:*"
    }
}
```

database/tsconfig.json

```json
{
    "$schema": "https://json.schemastore.org/tsconfig",
    "display": "Default",
    "compilerOptions": {
        "composite": false,
        "declaration": true,
        "declarationMap": true,
        "esModuleInterop": true,
        "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
        "inlineSources": false,
        "isolatedModules": true,
        "moduleResolution": "Node16",
        "module": "Node16",
        "noUnusedLocals": false,
        "noUnusedParameters": false,
        "preserveWatchOutput": true,
        "skipLibCheck": true,
        "strict": true
    },
    "exclude": ["node_modules"]
}
```

eslint-config-custom/package.json

```json
    "name": "eslint-config-custom",
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "main": "index.js",
    "license": "MIT",
    "scripts": {
        "format": "prettier --write ./*.js"
    },
    "dependencies": {
        "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^6.7.2",
        "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^6.7.2",
        "eslint": "^8.50.0",
        "eslint-config-next": "^13.4.19",
        "eslint-config-prettier": "^9.0.0",
        "eslint-config-turbo": "^1.10.14",
        "eslint-import-resolver-typescript": "^3.6.1",
        "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.28.1",
        "eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y": "^6.7.1",
        "eslint-plugin-react": "7.33.2",
        "eslint-plugin-react-hooks": "^4.6.0",
        "eslint-plugin-tailwindcss": "^3.13.0"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "typescript": "^5.2.2"
    },
    "publishConfig": {
        "access": "public"
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you checked https://github.com/typescript-eslint/typescript-eslint/issues/1464 ?

Comment: @Roy yes, the name is set at `.eslintrc.cjs`

Answer (score 0):

It ended up been a dumb mistake

I was doing `module.export` instead of `module.exports` where i am extending my config